# Is it possible to switch lxpanel to Bspwm panel without install the full Bspwm?

Tags: 18.04, customization, lxde

I am running ubuntu 18.04 with lxde, is it possible?

Comment: Lubuntu 18.04 LTS used LXDE with `openbox` as it's WM; yes `openbox` could be replaced with other WMs as LXDE is WM *agnostic*; but replacing the LXDE panel with a [WM extension](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/bspwm) makes little sense to me; why not just drop LXDE.

Answer (score 0):

`bspwm` does not have a status bar on its own. However, at least on Ubuntu, `lemonbar` is installed with it by default as a recommended package. Nothing is keeping you back from installing `lemonbar` separately and using it with different window managers or desktop environments.